# UIBarButtonItem bouncy rotation animation in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a custom `leftBarButtonItem` in `UINavigationBar`.

This `leftBarButtonItem` in initialized with custom view.

I tried many custom view's, from `UIButton` with background image to `UIView` with `UIImageView` as subview.

Custom view:

```
UIButton *leftButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);

[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:s] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Second custom view:

```
UIImageView *leftImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:s]];
[leftImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -15, 30, 30)];

UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[leftView addSubview:leftImageView];
```

The problem is that when I start rotating image in my custom view, image bounces slightly when rotating.

One of my examples for animation that doesn't work:

```
UIView *v = item.leftBarButtonItem.customView;

UIImageView *imageView;

for (UIView *subView in [v subviews]) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        imageView = (UIImageView *)subView;
    }
}

if (animating) {
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2 * M_PI];
    animation.duration = 1.0f;
    animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;

    v.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    [v.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
} else {
    [v.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

I would like to make rotation, where the center of the image stays the same all the time.

Any ideas?

Comment: where r u calling the animation ?

Comment: I am calling the animation in different controllers in their `viewDidLoad` method. Problem is that the animation is executing but the center of the image is moving, because of that the image get's the "bouncy" effect.

Comment: try to do it in view will appear. Also remove the anchor point line, it is of no use, by default anchor point is 0.5 for the layer.

Comment: Tried in `viewWillAppear` and removed the line with anchor point. Result is the same. Because I have a subclass of `UINavigationBar` I tried to add `UIBarButtonItem` in `layoutSubviews` method with no luck.